# Kendo Angular DataGrid - Cannot show aggregates in header

Tags: kendo-ui, datagrid, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to show the total count of the group in the group header with using a `kendoGridHeaderTemplate` as directed in

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GroupFooterTemplateDirective/

but instead using a kendoGridHeaderTemplate  instead of a `kendoGridFooterTemplate`, ref: 
http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GroupHeaderTemplateDirective/

Although the document specifies that the `aggregate` variable is available to both the header and the footer of the grid, it seems to work only with the footer. Is there anything else that needs to be done. Could the `group` property be used to achieve the same? How does one list all the properties available for the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have to use {{aggregates.aggregates[field].count}} instead of {{aggregates[field].count}} as demonstrated in http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GroupFooterTemplateDirective/